# Does ODataLib for OData V4 support Atom payload in requests?

Tags: odata, atom-feed, odatalib

I am trying to use ODataLib for OData protocol V4 (Microsoft.OData.Core) to generate payload in Atom format. I ensured that Content-Type and Accept headers refer application/atom+xml, however a call to CreateODataEntryWriter always result in exception:

> Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataContentTypeException : A supported MIME type
>   could not be found that matches the acceptable MIME types for the
>   request. The supported type(s)
>   'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=true,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=false,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=minimal,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false,
>   application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatib...'
>   do not match any of the acceptable MIME types 'application/atom+xml'.

Here's the sample code that cause the exception:

```
    var writerSettings = new ODataMessageWriterSettings();
    writerSettings.SetContentType(ODataFormat.Atom);
    var messageWriter = new ODataMessageWriter(request, writerSettings, model);
    var entryWriter = messageWriter.CreateODataEntryWriter();
```

I inspected the library code and found that ODataMessageWriterSettings has a property EnableAtom but this property is declared as internal, and it doesn't seem to be set from inside the library, so it looks like it is always false. I know that Atom format is obsolete in OData V4, is it supported for entry payload generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATOM is disabled since DataLib 6.3.0 release, see [release note](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/6.3.0).
Actually, you could use an ODataLib pre-6.3 release to generate ATOM payload, but new features in V4 may not be well supported.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.